# Prenex form and quantifiers (from LPL 11.37)

Tags: logic

i'm trying to solve the exercise 11.37 from LPL textbook (Logic Proof and Logic) and I'm blocked. I had to write a prenex normal form of each sentence. I tried a lot of times to do these two sentences:

```
¬∃x[Cube(x) ∧ ∀y (Tet(y) → ∃z Between(z, x, y))]
```

and

```
∃x Cube(x) ↔ ∀x Small(x)
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks.

Comment: I must write the prenex normal form of each sentence, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
~Ǝx[Cx & ∀y[Ty → Ǝz[Bzxy]]]
∀x[Cx → ~∀y[Ty → Ǝz[Bzxy]]]
∀x[Cx → ~∀y[Ǝz[Ty → Bzxy]]]
∀x[Cx → Ǝy[∀z[~(Ty → Bzxy)]]]
∀x[Ǝy[Cx → ∀z[~(Ty → Bzxy)]]]
∀x[Ǝy[∀z[Cx → ~(Ty → Bzxy)]]]
∀x[Ǝy[∀z[Cx → ~(~Ty ∨ Bzxy)]]]
∀x[Ǝy[∀z[Cx → (Ty & ~Bzxy)]]]
```

And the second one:

```
Ǝx[Cx] ⇔ ∀x[Sx]
(Ǝx[Cx] → ∀x[Sx]) & (∀x[Sx] → Ǝx[Cx]) rename
(Ǝx[Cx] → ∀y[Sy]) & (∀z[Sz] → Ǝw[Cw])
(∀x[Cx → ∀y[Sy]]) & (Ǝz[Sz → Ǝw[Cw]])
∀x[∀y[Cx → Sy] & Ǝz[Ǝw[Sz → Cw]]]
∀x[∀y[(Cx → Sy) & Ǝz[Ǝw[Sz → Cw]]]]
∀x[∀y[Ǝz[Ǝw[(Sz → Cw) & (Cx → Sy)]]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

The first exercise could be transformed in the following way:
 1. ¬∃x [Cube(x) ∧ ∀y (Tet(y) → ∃z Between(z,x,y))]
 2. ∀x ¬[Cube(x) ∧ ∀y (Tet(y) → ∃z Between(z,x,y))] - De Morgan's law for quantifiers
 3. ∀x [¬Cube(x) ∨ ¬∀y (Tet(y) → ∃z Between(z,x,y))] - De Morgan's law for propositional logic
 4. ∀x [¬Cube(x) ∨ ∃y ¬(Tet(y) → ∃z Between(z,x,y))] - De Morgan's law for quantifiers
 5. ∀x [¬Cube(x) ∨ ∃y ¬(¬Tet(y) ∨ ∃z Between(z,x,y))]- replace implication
 6. ∀x∃y [¬Cube(x) ∨ ¬(¬Tet(y) ∨ ∃z Between(z,x,y))] - pull out y-variable applying null quantification principle
 7. ∀x∃y [¬Cube(x) ∨ (¬¬Tet(y) ∧ ¬∃z Between(z,x,y))] - inject negation into the parenthesis using De Morgan's law for propositional logic
 8. ∀x∃y [¬Cube(x) ∨ (Tet(y) ∧ ¬∃z Between(z,x,y))] - cancel double negation in front of Tet(y) using negation elimination rule
 9. ∀x∃y [¬Cube(x) ∨ (Tet(y) ∧ ∀z ¬Between(z,x,y))] - De Morgan's law for quantifiers
 10. ∀x∃y∀z [¬Cube(x) ∨ (Tet(y) ∧ ¬Between(z,x,y))] - null quantification principle for z-variable
 11. ∀x∃y∀z [Cube(x) → (Tet(y) ∧ ¬Between(z,x,y))] - replace disjunction by implication ∎

Comment: It seems like more is needed here. What I think you have is ¬∃x[Cube].

Comment: Please, could you advice on how to add latex typesetting into my answer? I have not found any guideline.

Comment: Latex is not available on this site the way MathJax is on the math SE. I did not down-vote your answer. Best wishes.

Comment: You could cut and paste from the other answer to get the symbols.

Comment: (Obsolete comment, please delete)